# Getting data from a file with different lengths of data c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get grades from a txt file

```
    NAME           ID    AM_CLASSES AM_GRADES GRADES    AM_GRADES   GRADES AM_GRADES     GRADES     AM_GRADES    GRADES
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SMITH, John        111000000      4     4   80 89 80 77   3      100 100 90     4   89 90 95 85     3          95 100 90
GONZALES, Pedro    111002210      3     3   42 100 67     3      90 100 95      4   99 80 85 95
JOHNSON, Rose      111001100      4     2   77 90         4      95 67 90 95    4   89 90 95 75     3          95 88 90
```

in order to be able to calculate their average, I have done this problem in the past with a set amount of data for each student using this type of code:

```
while (stIn>>name>>lastName>>ID>>grade1>>grade2>>grade3)
```

but it doesn't work for this type of problem as each student has a different amount of classes and grades, plus there is a header in the txt file which I don't know how to skip. I tried using

```
string line;
while(getline(stIn,line))
```

but I don't know how to skip the first 2 lines or how to extract the data from the string into variables to be able to be used in my calculations without using stringstream as shown in other questions, sadly I can't use stringstream as it hasn't been taught yet and will earn me a 0 (has happened in the past). For now our classes have only been up to arrays and vectors so I'm thinking of using a vector to take in the data but it hasn't worked out yet. I'm open to any suggestions on getting the data thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data may be variable length, but it has a pattern to it.  You can make use of `operator>>`, as each class list is preceded by the number of classes, and each grades list is preceded by the number of grades.

Try something like this:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

struct student
{
    string lastName;
    string firstName;
    int id;
    vector<vector<int> > grades;
};

ifstream stIn("file.txt");

// skip the header
stIn.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
stIn.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

vector<student> students;
string name;
int count;

while (getline(stIn, name, ','))
{
    student s;

    s.lastName = name;
    stIn >> s.firstName;

    stIn >> s.id;

    stIn >> count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        int num, value;
        vector<int> vec;

        stIn >> num;
        for (int j = 0; j < num; ++j)
        {
            stIn >> value;
            vec.push_back(value);
        }

        s.grades.push_back(vec);
    }

    stIn.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    students.push_back(s);
}

// use students as needed...
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/g7GnbN)

Answer (score 1):

Using a little data analysis you can see that the data is structured like so:

```
HEADER
Separator
Student...
Student...
Student...
...
```

The `HEADER` and `Separator` entries are skippable, otherwise the records are formatted where there is one `Student` per row and a `Student` record is structured as a whitespace-delimited entry:

```
LAST_NAME, First_Name Id Class_count Classes...
```

and a `Class` is a sub-record likewise formatted as a whitespace-delimited entry that's part of `Student`:

```
Grades_count Grades...
```

Using this information you can implement your file read like this:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Class {
    std:vector<int> grades{};
    std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Class& c) {
        std::size_t count{};
        is >> count;
        grades.resize(count);
        for(auto& g : grades) {
            is >> g;
        }
        return is;
    }
};

struct Student {
    std::string last_name{};
    std::string first_name{};
    std::size_t id{};
    std::vector<Class> classes{};
    std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Student& student) {
        is >> last_name;
        last_name.pop_back() //Remove comma
        is >> first_name;
        is >> id;
        std::size_t classCount{};
        is >> classCount;
        classes.resize(classCount);
        for(auto& c : classes) {
            is >> c;
        }
        return is;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::ifstream infile("grades.txt");
    { //cur_line doesn't need to exist past the first two line reads.
    std::string cur_line{};
    std::getline(infile, cur_line); //Skip HEADER
    std::getline(infile, cur_line); //Skip Separator
    }
    Student student;
    while(infile >> student) { //Read to the end of the file.
        //..."Do The Thing!"(tm) with the current record;
        //including storing it somewhere.
    }
}
```

Optionally, if you know the `Class` data type isn't going to be used anywhere else and is internal to `Student` you can declare it as an internal `struct`:

```cpp
struct Student {
    struct Class {
        //...
    };
    //...
    std::vector<Student::Class> classes{};
};
```